# Jenkins Jira-trigger plugin "Build is scheduled for ..." stopped writing to Jira comment

Tags: jenkins-jira-trigger

Up until about this May, the Jenkins Trigger plugin was writing the "Build is scheduled for" message in Jira comment when the build was scheduled by a Jira webhook. It stopped working since then. I can write the comment to the Jira API so it looks like the issue in on the jira-trigger plugin. Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution. It looks like we need to login manually to the Jira site as the Jenkins user to clear out dialog boxes that were added when Jira changed licensing models.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar strange problem, the **"Build is scheduled for"** message and trigger job building work fine yesterday, but not work today. The Jenkins plugin log seem fine **"Received Webhook callback from changelog. Event type: jira:issue_updated"**. But no **"Build is scheduled for"** message in Jira and no related Jenkins build trigger.

I check the Jira user in Jenkins config, then log in Jira, I find there is a notification about authentication in Jenkins. Bad Requestoauth_problem **"timestamp_refused"**, I will check the time on Jira and Jenkins server.
Related link: [oauth-error-oauth_problem-timestamp_refused](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/oauth-error-oauth_problem-timestamp_refused-720406801.html)